# Limits of points along X-Axis of the 2-variable function

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, limits-without-lhopital

Let $f:\Re
^2\rightarrow\Re$ be a real-valued function such that f(x,y) is defined as,
$$f(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
xsin(1/y),& \text{if $y\neq 0$} \\[2ex]
0,& \text{if $y=0$}
\end{cases}$$
The question is to  find $ \lim_{(x,y)\to (a,0)}f(x,y)$,$a\in\Re$.I was able to prove the limit for the point (0,0) is equal to 0.However,for points other than (0,0),the limit does not exist(correct me if I'm wrong) as $sin(1/y)$ oscillates between 1 and -1 as $y\rightarrow 0$ but how do I prove it using $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition for the limit of a function?Or is there any other way to prove it?

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ had limit in $(a,0)$ it would have limit for every direction you approach $(a, 0)$.
Instead, if you go to $(a, 0)$ on the straight line $x=a$ you have $\lim_{y\to 0} f(a, t)=a\lim_{y\to 0} \sin (\frac 1y)$ that doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks!So,is it sufficient to prove that the $\lim_{y\to 0}sin(1/y)$ does not exist?I was confused because at the point (0,0),the limit of the function exists but $\lim_{y\to 0}sin(1/y)$ does not exist going by your process.

Comment: @user631874 in fact my proof is correct only if $a\ne 0$. What you said is correct